# Set Date on JDateChooser

Tags: java, database

im trying to get Date from my database into a JDateChooser field

```
TglSuratMasuk.setText(rs.getDate("tgl_surat_masuk"));
```

that is what i've been trying, sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is a `TglSuratMasuk`?  What variable type is it?

Comment: I imagine that `ResultSet#getDate` is returning an instance of `java.sql.Date`, but `JDateChooser#setText` is expecting a `String`, so, yep, that's not going to work.  Maybe instead, have a look if `JDateChooser` has a `setDate` value instead

Comment: TglSuratMasuk is an variable name of my JDateChooser field

Comment: 'TglSuratMasuk.setDate(rs.getDate("tgl_surat_masuk"));' i've try doing this but it just give me a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ResultSet#getDate` returns an instance of `java.sql.Date` and `JDateChooser#setText` expects a `String`, this approach isn't going to work.

Instead, you should use the `setDate` method of `JDateChooser` instead.

Maybe something more like:

```
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = rs.getDate("tgl_surat_masuk");
 TglSuratMasuk.setDate(sqlDate);
```

> 'TglSuratMasuk.setDate(rs.getDate("tgl_surat_masuk"));' i've try doing this but it just give me a nullpointerexception

This means that either the `ResultSet` doesn't include a column called `tgl_surat_masuk` or the column type is not stored in a valid "date" type.  You need to go back to your database and query and verify the type which is been stored